# Get YouTube channel content in iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I would like to create a small test app for iOS in which I get youtube videos from a specific channel. I would also like to get the comments in the channel and such.

How can this be done? Does the iOS API (Youtube) support this. Didn't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube does have a Objective-C api. You can look through the example applications 
[here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples). Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Not understandable in link